# Maps Engine polygons coordinates not exact to Google Maps coordinates?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-engine

I made two polygons using Google Maps Engine, then I export them as KML file.
The two areas is located in SPAIN as you see in the picture below:

[image: On Google Maps Engine]

On Android development I use Google Maps API and I put the coordinates in a new `PolygonOptions` that I was export in the KML file.
When I run the app I got this result:

[image: On Google Maps API for Android]

I don't know where the two polygons are located !! there are not in Spain.

Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to pass latitude and longitude in different order.

Check this [point here](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/Plaza+Maestro+Haedo,+6,+49003+Zamora,+Spain/@41.5037669,-5.7442717,17z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0xd391e314209d533:0x90afa6fa8160aa61) **41°30'13.7"N 5°44'40.3"W**

And [now this](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/5%C2%B044'39.4%22S+41%C2%B030'13.6%22E/@-5.7424994,41.5037669,8z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0) is what if you reverse the order: **5°44'40.3"S 41°30'13.7"E**

Comment: You're right, thank you Mr Andrey you save my day :)